# CodeIgniter output to profiler

Tags: codeigniter

Is it possible to output custom data to the CI profiler?

I tried

```
$this->output->append_output($var);
```

But this seems to be similar to an echo, as it appears at the top of the page.

Is there a way to get this to appear with the rest of the profiling info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend the profiler class:

```
class MY_Profiler extends CI_Profiler {

    function _do_stuff() {
        //do stuff
    }

    //In the run method add your method
    function run() {
        $this->_do_stuff();
    }

}
```

This is something from my blog: http://pinoytech.org/blog/post/Add-SESSIONS-to-Profiler-in-CodeIgniter

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can set which sections you want to show

1.Add this to controller method which you want to profile:

```
$sections = array(
'config'  => TRUE,
'queries' => TRUE
);

$this->output->set_profiler_sections($sections);
$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
```

2.In  application/config/profiler.php set application wide defaults:

```
$config['config'] = FALSE;
$config['queries'] = FALSE;
```

Here is list of all available sections: (by the way this can be found under system/libraries/profiler.php

```
'benchmarks',
'get',
'memory_usage',
'post',
'uri_string',
'controller_info',
'queries',
'http_headers',
'session_data',
'config'
```